# Why does my vertex moving cause my object to move?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Im trying to add imperfections to my donut and i have snapping off but everytime i select a vertex and hit g to move it the entire object snaps to my cursor and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: maybe you have activated the Propotional Editing option?

Comment: thank you for the replies i realised that i had my proportional editing too high and just needed to turn it down :)